# Best practice for using same functions between classes

Tags: swift

In swift, what is best practice for having several functions common to more than one class, where inheritance between those classes isn't feasible?

I'm new to programming so please don't condescend.  Its just when I first started learning a few months ago I was told its terrible practice to repeat code, and at the time I was coding in Ruby where I could create a module in which all the functions resided, and then just include module in any class where I wanted to use those functions.  As long as all variables in the module's functions were declared in the classes the code worked.

Is there a similar practice in swift, or should I be doing something else like making a bunch of global functions and passing the instance variables to those functions?  Please be as specific as possible as I'm gonna follow your advice for all code I write in swift going forward, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple answer to your question is protocol

define protocol

```
protocol ProtocolName {
    /* common functions */
    func echoTestString()
}

extension ProtocolName {
    /* default implementation */        
    func echoTestString() {
        print("default string")
    }
}
```

class conforming to protocol with default implementation

```
class ClassName: ProtocolName {

}

ClassName().echoTestString() // default string
```

class conforming to protocol with overriden implementation

```
class AnotherClass: ProtocolName {

    func echoTestString() {
        print("my string")
    }
}

AnotherClass().echoTestString() // my string
```

Answer (score 0):

While an opinion, I think this is the right route - use a Framework target. Protocols work too. But with a Framework, you can:

- Share across projects
- Keep everything local in scope what you need or not
- Be agnostic in many ways

If you want to use the "include" Swift verb (and all that comes with it), you pretty much need to use a Framework target. If you want complete splitting of code too. Protocols are used when you are within a single project, do not want to "repeat" code pieces, and know you will always be local.

If what you want is to (a) use protocols across projects, (b) include true separate code, (c) have global functions, while (d) passing instance variables... consider a separate target.

EDIT: Looking at your question title ("using same functions") and thinking about OOP versus functional programming, I thought I'd add something that doesn't change my solution but enhances it - functional programming means you can "pass" a function as a parameter. I don't think that's what you were saying, but it's another piece of being Swifty in your coding.